# kubernetes skydns failure to forward request

Tags: dns, kubernetes, skydns

I am creating a cluster of 1 master 2 nodes kubernetes. I am trying to create the skydns based on the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: kube-dns-v11
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
    version: v11
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
    version: v11
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: kube-dns
        version: v11
        kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: etcd
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/etcd-amd64:2.2.1
        # resources:
        #   # TODO: Set memory limits when we've profiled the container for large
        #   # clusters, then set request = limit to keep this container in
        #   # guaranteed class. Currently, this container falls into the
        #   # "burstable" category so the kubelet doesn't backoff from restarting it.
        #   limits:
        #     cpu: 100m
        #     memory: 500Mi
        #   requests:
        #     cpu: 100m
        #     memory: 50Mi
        command:
        - /usr/local/bin/etcd
        - -data-dir
        - /var/etcd/data
        - -listen-client-urls
        - http://127.0.0.1:2379,http://127.0.0.1:4001
        - -advertise-client-urls
        - http://127.0.0.1:2379,http://127.0.0.1:4001
        - -initial-cluster-token
        - skydns-etcd
        volumeMounts:
        - name: etcd-storage
          mountPath: /var/etcd/data
      - name: kube2sky
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/kube2sky:1.14
        # resources:
        #   # TODO: Set memory limits when we've profiled the container for large
        #   # clusters, then set request = limit to keep this container in
        #   # guaranteed class. Currently, this container falls into the
        #   # "burstable" category so the kubelet doesn't backoff from restarting it.
        #   limits:
        #     cpu: 100m
        #     # Kube2sky watches all pods.
        #     memory: 200Mi
        #   requests:
        #     cpu: 100m
        #     memory: 50Mi
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          timeoutSeconds: 5
          # successThreshold: 1
          # failureThreshold: 5
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /readiness
            port: 8081
            scheme: HTTP
          # we poll on pod startup for the Kubernetes master service and
          # only setup the /readiness HTTP server once that's available.
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        args:
        # command = "/kube2sky"
        - --domain=cluster.local
      - name: skydns
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/skydns:2015-10-13-8c72f8c
        resources:
          # TODO: Set memory limits when we've profiled the container for large
          # clusters, then set request = limit to keep this container in
          # guaranteed class. Currently, this container falls into the
          # "burstable" category so the kubelet doesn't backoff from restarting it.
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 50Mi
        args:
        # command = "/skydns"
        - -machines=http://127.0.0.1:4001
        - -addr=0.0.0.0:53
        - -ns-rotate=false
        - -domain=cluster.local
        ports:
        - containerPort: 53
          name: dns
          protocol: UDP
        - containerPort: 53
          name: dns-tcp
          protocol: TCP
      - name: healthz
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/exechealthz:1.0
        # resources:
        #   # keep request = limit to keep this container in guaranteed class
        #   limits:
        #     cpu: 10m
        #     memory: 20Mi
        #   requests:
        #     cpu: 10m
        #     memory: 20Mi
        args:
        - -cmd=nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local 127.0.0.1 >/dev/null
        - -port=8080
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
      volumes:
      - name: etcd-storage
        emptyDir: {}
      dnsPolicy: Default  # Don't use cluster DNS.
```

However, skydns is spitting out the following:

```
> $kubectl logs kube-dns-v11-k07j9 --namespace=kube-system  skydns 
> 2016/04/18 12:47:05 skydns: falling back to default configuration,
> could not read from etcd: 100: Key not found (/skydns) [1]  2016/04/18
> 12:47:05 skydns: ready for queries on cluster.local. for
> tcp://0.0.0.0:53 [rcache 0]  2016/04/18 12:47:05 skydns: ready for
> queries on cluster.local. for udp://0.0.0.0:53 [rcache 0]  2016/04/18
> 12:47:11 skydns: failure to forward request "read udp
>     192.168.122.1:53: i/o timeout" 2016/04/18 12:47:15 skydns: failure to forward request "read udp 192.168.122.1:53: i/o timeout" 2016/04/18
> 12:47:19 skydns: failure to forward request "read udp
>     192.168.122.1:53: i/o timeout" 2016/04/18 12:47:23 skydns: failure to forward request "read udp 192.168.122.1:53: i/o timeout" 2016/04/18
> 12:47:27 skydns: failure to forward request "read udp
>     192.168.122.1:53: i/o timeout" 2016/04/18 12:47:31 skydns: failure to forward request "read udp 192.168.122.1:53: i/o timeout" 2016/04/18
> 12:47:35 skydns: failure to forward request "read udp
>     192.168.122.1:53: i/o timeout" 2016/04/18 12:47:39 skydns: failure to forward request "read udp 192.168.122.1:53: i/o timeout" 2016/04/18
> 12:47:43 skydns: failure to forward request "read udp
>     192.168.122.1:53: i/o timeout" 2016/04/18 12:47:47 skydns: failure to forward request "read udp 192.168.122.1:53: i/o timeout" 2016/04/18
> 12:47:51 skydns: failure to forward request "read udp
>     192.168.122.1:53: i/o timeout" 2016/04/18 12:47:55 skydns: failure to forward request "read udp 192.168.122.1:53: i/o timeout" 2016/04/18
> 12:47:59 skydns: failure to forward request "read udp
>     192.168.122.1:53: i/o timeout" 2016/04/18 12:48:03 skydns: failure to forward request "read udp 192.168.122.1:53: i/o timeout"
```

After looking further, I just realized what is a 192.168.122.1? It is virtual switch on kvm. Why is skydns trying to hit my virtual switch or dns server of virtual machine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SkyDNS` defaults its forwarding nameservers to the one listed in `/etc/resolv.conf`. Since `SkyDNS` runs inside the `kube-dns` pod as a cluster addon, it inherits its `/etc/resolv.conf` from its host as described in the [`kube-dns` doc](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/dns#inheriting-dns-from-the-node).

From your question, it looks like your host's `/etc/resolv.conf` is configured to use 192.168.122.1 as its nameserver and hence that becomes the forwarding server in your `SkyDNS` config. I believe 192.168.122.1 is not routable from your Kubernetes cluster and that's why you are seeing "failure to forward request" errors in the `kube-dns` logs.

The simplest solution to this problem is to supply a reachable DNS server as a flag to `SkyDNS` in your RC config. Here is an example (it's just your RC config, but adds the `-nameservers` flag in the `SkyDNS` container spec):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: kube-dns-v11
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
    version: v11
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
    version: v11
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: kube-dns
        version: v11
        kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: etcd
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/etcd-amd64:2.2.1
        # resources:
        #   # TODO: Set memory limits when we've profiled the container for large
        #   # clusters, then set request = limit to keep this container in
        #   # guaranteed class. Currently, this container falls into the
        #   # "burstable" category so the kubelet doesn't backoff from restarting it.
        #   limits:
        #     cpu: 100m
        #     memory: 500Mi
        #   requests:
        #     cpu: 100m
        #     memory: 50Mi
        command:
        - /usr/local/bin/etcd
        - -data-dir
        - /var/etcd/data
        - -listen-client-urls
        - http://127.0.0.1:2379,http://127.0.0.1:4001
        - -advertise-client-urls
        - http://127.0.0.1:2379,http://127.0.0.1:4001
        - -initial-cluster-token
        - skydns-etcd
        volumeMounts:
        - name: etcd-storage
          mountPath: /var/etcd/data
      - name: kube2sky
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/kube2sky:1.14
        # resources:
        #   # TODO: Set memory limits when we've profiled the container for large
        #   # clusters, then set request = limit to keep this container in
        #   # guaranteed class. Currently, this container falls into the
        #   # "burstable" category so the kubelet doesn't backoff from restarting it.
        #   limits:
        #     cpu: 100m
        #     # Kube2sky watches all pods.
        #     memory: 200Mi
        #   requests:
        #     cpu: 100m
        #     memory: 50Mi
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          timeoutSeconds: 5
          # successThreshold: 1
          # failureThreshold: 5
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /readiness
            port: 8081
            scheme: HTTP
          # we poll on pod startup for the Kubernetes master service and
          # only setup the /readiness HTTP server once that's available.
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        args:
        # command = "/kube2sky"
        - --domain=cluster.local
      - name: skydns
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/skydns:2015-10-13-8c72f8c
        resources:
          # TODO: Set memory limits when we've profiled the container for large
          # clusters, then set request = limit to keep this container in
          # guaranteed class. Currently, this container falls into the
          # "burstable" category so the kubelet doesn't backoff from restarting it.
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 50Mi
        args:
        # command = "/skydns"
        - -machines=http://127.0.0.1:4001
        - -addr=0.0.0.0:53
        - -ns-rotate=false
        - -domain=cluster.local
        - -nameservers=8.8.8.8:53,8.8.4.4:53  # Adding this flag. Dont use double quotes.
        ports:
        - containerPort: 53
          name: dns
          protocol: UDP
        - containerPort: 53
          name: dns-tcp
          protocol: TCP
      - name: healthz
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/exechealthz:1.0
        # resources:
        #   # keep request = limit to keep this container in guaranteed class
        #   limits:
        #     cpu: 10m
        #     memory: 20Mi
        #   requests:
        #     cpu: 10m
        #     memory: 20Mi
        args:
        - -cmd=nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local 127.0.0.1 >/dev/null
        - -port=8080
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
      volumes:
      - name: etcd-storage
        emptyDir: {}
      dnsPolicy: Default  # Don't use cluster DNS.
```

Comment: I got  this error when logs the pod :"etcdmain: listen tcp: lookup localhost on 202.96.199.133:53: read udp 172.17.0.2:36311->202.96.199.133:53: i/o timeout"

Comment: listen tcp: lookup localhost on 8.8.8.8:53: read udp 172.17.0.6:37954->8.8.8.8:53: i/o timeout

Comment: i am seeing the same problems with this setup: https://github.com/stephanlindauer/terra-aws-core-kube
any news on this?