# pods can't resolve DNS after 'oc cluster up'

Tags: openshift

On a fresh install of RHEL7.4:

```
# install the oc client and docker
[root@openshift1 ~]# yum install atomic-openshift-clients.x86_64 docker

# configure and start docker
[root@openshift1 ~]# sed -i '/^\[registries.insecure\]/!b;n;cregistries = ['172.30.0.0\/16']' /etc/containers/registries.conf
[root@openshift1 ~]# systemctl start docker; systemctl enable docker

# these links recommend running 'iptables -F' as a workaround for pod DNS issues
# https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/12110
# https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/10139

[root@openshift1 ~]# iptables -F; iptables -F -t nat

[root@openshift1 ~]# oc cluster up --public-hostname 192.168.146.200
```

Attempting a test apache build gives me this error:

```
Cloning "https://github.com/openshift/httpd-ex.git " ...
WARNING: timed out waiting for git server, will wait 1m4s
error: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/openshift/httpd-ex.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com; Unknown error
```

DNS server is present

```
[root@openshift1 ~]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 192.168.146.2
```

I can confirm that the host machine can resolve names:

```
[root@openshift1 ~]# host github.com
github.com has address 192.30.255.113
github.com has address 192.30.255.112
```

However this DNS server didn't make it's way down to the pods

```
[root@openshift1 ~]# oc get pods
NAME                            READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
docker-registry-1-rqm9h         1/1       Running   0          38s
persistent-volume-setup-fdbv5   1/1       Running   0          50s
router-1-m6z8w                  1/1       Running   0          31s

[root@openshift1 ~]# oc rsh docker-registry-1-rqm9h
sh-4.2$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 172.30.0.1
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
options ndots:5
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Not sure if you had gone through [prerequisites](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/install/prerequisites.html#prereq-dns)

Comment: I honestly haven't, and thanks for pointing it out. I checked the DNS requirement, and I am satisfying it. I'm running my standalone openshift host on a VMWare Workstation which provides DNS service on the NAT adapter. /etc/resolv.conf is proper on the openshift host and I can resolve names. However the DNS entry does not trickle down to the pods. NetworkManager is enabled and running.

Comment: Please also check dnsmasq configuration, usually in `/etc/dnsmasq.d` folder.

Comment: there's no /etc/dnsmasq.d folder, nor any dnsmaq.d directory in /var/lib/origin
`

Comment: As shown in prerequisites, Openshift relies on Dnsmasq to resolve domain name. If Dnsmasq is not properly installed and configured, pod can not resolve domain name.

Answer (score 2):

You should not flush the rules, rather you should create a new zone and open additional ports, e.g.:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --new-zone dockerc
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone dockerc --add-source $(docker network inspect -f "{{range .IPAM.Config }}{{ .Subnet }}{{end}}" bridge)
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone dockerc --add-port 8443/tcp --add-port 53/udp --add-port 8053/udp
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Source:
https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/release-3.7/docs/cluster_up_down.md#linux

EDIT:
Also the DNS server in your /etc/resolv.conf should be routable from your OCP instance.

Source: [kubernetes skydns failure to forward request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36694769/kubernetes-skydns-failure-to-forward-request)

Comment: In my case your answer solve my problem, that I was using 443, just added into existing dockerc zone